# angular service doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I did pretty simple [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NGEe4aRp5FV9soQ8pXpO?p=preview) to show my problem. The problem is I have variable and I want to populate this variable with initial app loading, I did angular services for this purpose, but for some reason angular services doesn't fire inside controller. Where is my mistake?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, optService) {

  $scope.priority = [];

  var exeService = function() {

    console.log('function fired')
     // this is firing
      optService.myOptions(function (result) {

        console.log('service fired')
     // this is not firing
          angular.forEach(result, function(value) {

              $scope.priority.push({value: value.name, label: value.name});

          });
      });
   }
  exeService()
  console.log($scope.priority)
  // shows an empty array
});
```

services

```
(function () {

angular.module("app").factory("optService", ["$http", "$rootScope", "$q", "$log",
    function ($http, $rootScope, $q, $log) {

        var clearApi = "test.json";


        function myOptions () {
            return $http.get(clearApi)
                .then(function (response) {
                  console.log(response.data)
                  // shows an array
                    return response.data;
                });
        } 

        return {
          myOptions: myOptions
        }

        }])
}());
```

Comment: the function `myOptions` defined in your service doesn't have any argument, so why are you calling `optService.myOptions(function (result)` in your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the service declaration like that:

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'optService', function($scope, optService) {
```

and in the controller

```
  optService.myOptions().then(function (result) {

    console.log('service fired')

      angular.forEach(result, function(value) {

          $scope.priority.push({value: value.name, label: value.name});

      });
  });
```

Comment: Of course, I forgot .then cause I don't use an argument. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with then but declaraction with array isn't mandatory

Comment: Yes of course but it will be a good thing if he ll minify his project

Comment: a talked about  'app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope, optService) {'  instead of ' app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'optService', function($scope, optService) {'